# Conditional expectation of product of independent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Given $X_i$, $i=1,...,n$ are Bernoulli(p) independent and identically distributed.

I want to find $E[X_1X_2X_3X_4 |S=s]$ where $S=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$.

But i'm stuck on how to find such expectation, should i find first the conjointy probability? And If so How can i?

Comment: The answer that you accepted is not correct (e.g. note that the answer is definitely $1$ in special case $n=s=4$, so not $p^4$). However an accepted answer cannot be deleted. This is an awkward situation for the author of the answer and you can help him out by withdrawing your acceptance. Another possibility is that the author changes his answer in such a way that it becomes an acceptable answer afterwards.

Comment: Would never notice this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Guide**:

$X_1X_2X_3X_4$ only contains values in $\{0,1\}$ so that: $$\mathbb E[X_1X_2X_3X_4\mid S=s]=P(X_1X_2X_3X_4=1\mid S=s)=$$$$P(X_1=X_2=X_3=X_4=1\mid S=s)$$

So it comes to finding the probability that the first $4$ experiments are successes under the condition that in total $s$ of the $n$ experiments are successes.

**Addendum**:

Note that $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has $\binom{n}{s}$ subsets of cardinality $s$ and that by $s$ successes each of these sets has equal probability to be the "success"-set (i.e. the set $\{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\mid X_i=1\}$). Further $\binom{n-4}{s-4}$ of these sets contains $\{1,2,3,4\}$ as a subset. From this we conclude that:$$E[X_1X_2X_3X_4\mid S=s]=P(X_1=X_2=X_3=X_4=1\mid S=s)=\frac{\binom{n-4}{s-4}}{\binom{n}{s}}$$
This under the convention that $\binom{n-4}{s-4}=0$ if $s<4$

---

Also you can go for: 
$$\begin{aligned}P\left(X_{1}=X_{2}=X_{3}=X_{4}=1\mid\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}=s\right) & =\frac{P\left(X_{1}=X_{2}=X_{3}=X_{4}=1\wedge\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}=s\right)}{P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}=s\right)}\\
 & =\frac{P\left(X_{1}=X_{2}=X_{3}=X_{4}=1\wedge\sum_{i=5}^{n}X_{i}=s-4\right)}{P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}=s\right)}\\
 & =\frac{p^{4}P\left(\sum_{i=5}^{n}X_{i}=s-4\right)}{P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}=s\right)}\\
 & =\frac{p^{4}\binom{n-4}{s-4}p^{s-4}\left(1-p\right)^{n-s}}{\binom{n}{s}p^{s}\left(1-p\right)^{n-s}}\\
 & =\frac{\binom{n-4}{s-4}}{\binom{n}{s}}
\end{aligned}
$$